Animations Not Exporting as FBX
So I'm trying to export this model with all of it's animations, but every time I click export, it doesn't include any of the animations. I did this yesterday with a similar model and everything exported fine (I am trying to import the assets to UE5), but today for some reason it's not working. I have no idea what I'm doing differently. I tried disabling NLA Strips and All Actions, both together and separately, but nothing seems to work.


